# flatten a complex dict, while compressing keys using dot as a separator

Tags: python, json, recursion, nested, flatten

I'm trying come up with a python3 function (using existing libs also works, of course) that would flatten this input:

```
{
  'key1': 1, 
  'key2dict': {'subkey1': 1, 'subkey2': 2},
  'key3listOfDict': [
    {'subkey3': 3, 'subkey4': 4},
    {'subkey5': 5, 'subkey6': 6}
  ],
  'key4nestedListOfDict': [
    {
      'subkey7': 7, 
      'subkeyNested': [
        {'subkey8': 8}, 
        {'subkey9': 9}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

into this:

```
[
  {
    'key1': 1, 
    'key2dict.subkey1': 1,
    'key2dict.subkey2': 2,
    'key3listOfDict.subkey3': 3,
    'key3listOfDict.subkey4': 4,
    'key4nestedListOfDict.subkey7': 7,
    'key4nestedListOfDict.subkeyNested.subkey8': 8,
  },
  {
    'key1': 1, 
    'key2dict.subkey1': 1,
    'key2dict.subkey2': 2,
    'key3listOfDict.subkey3': 3,
    'key3listOfDict.subkey4': 4,
    'key4nestedListOfDict.subkey7': 7,
    'key4nestedListOfDict.subkeyNested.subkey9': 9,
  },
  {
    'key1': 1, 
    'key2dict.subkey1': 1,
    'key2dict.subkey2': 2,
    'key3listOfDict.subkey5': 5,
    'key3listOfDict.subkey6': 6,
    'key4nestedListOfDict.subkey7': 7,
    'key4nestedListOfDict.subkeyNested.subkey8': 8,
  },
  {
    'key1': 1, 
    'key2dict.subkey1': 1,
    'key2dict.subkey2': 2,
    'key3listOfDict.subkey5': 5,
    'key3listOfDict.subkey6': 6,
    'key4nestedListOfDict.subkey7': 7,
    'key4nestedListOfDict.subkeyNested.subkey9': 9,
  }
]
```

The main challenge I'm having is the proper handling the lists-of-objects, and nested lists-of-objects.
I researched and tried some myself, but those didn't work as expected.

Any help would be much appreciated!

for the record, I have these so far (not doing the work properly..):

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping

def flatten(dictionary, parent_key='', separator='.'):
    items = []
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        new_key = parent_key + separator + key if parent_key else key
        if isinstance(value, MutableMapping):
            items.extend(flatten(value, new_key, separator=separator).items())
        else:
            items.append((new_key, value))
    return dict(items)

def flatten_handle_lists(row):
    rows = []
    for i, (key, value) in enumerate(row.items()):
        if isinstance(value, list):
            for j, v in enumerate(value):
                expansion_row = dict(row)
                del expansion_row[key]
                expansion_row.update(flatten(v, key, '.'))
                rows.append(expansion_row)
    return rows
```

Comment: You have some closing brackets `]` in your output that don't look like they belong. Am I correct that you want the product of arrays of dictionaries? What about arrays of other values?

Comment: When you have a list of dictionaries, are all their keys always different?

Comment: Yep you're right @PatrickHaugh, thanks. I updated the output. 
[> Am I correct that you want the product of arrays of dictionaries? ]
yes, in a way that makes sense like the example I put.

[>What about arrays of other values?]
I don't expect issues with anything other than object within arrays. From what I experiences those are flattened and their keys compresses with less complexity.

Comment: @Barmar - 
[> When you have a list of dictionaries, are all their keys always different? ]
hmm not always, but I don't have any constraint that would make them always the same (from count and type perspective), thus I intended my example to handle the most complex case I may expect.

Comment: Now that I look at the desired result more carefully I see that it doesn't matter, since they end up in different elements of the final list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much simpler to split this into two steps: handle the lists first, then do the dictionary flattening afterward.

```python
import itertools
from collections.abc import Mapping


def explode_nested_lists(dictionary):
    """
    Turn a nested dictionary with lists representing different possible subtrees
    into a list of dictionaries for each combination of the subtrees.
    """
    options = {}
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            options[k] = list(itertools.chain(*map(explode_nested_lists, v)))
        elif isinstance(v, Mapping):
            options[k] = explode_nested_lists(v)
        else:
            options[k] = [v]
    keys = list(options.keys())
    return [
        dict(zip(keys, vals)) for vals in itertools.product(*(options[k] for k in keys))
    ]


def flatten_keys(dictionary, separator="."):
    """Flatten a nested dictionary by joining keys with a separator."""
    result = {}
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(value, Mapping):
            result.update(
                (key + separator + k, v)
                for k, v in flatten_keys(value, separator).items()
            )
        else:
            result[key] = value
    return result


def flatten(dictionary, separator="."):
    return [flatten_keys(d, separator) for d in explode_nested_lists(dictionary)]
```

Comment: Yeah I understand what you mean.. I got stuck on attempting to do the flattening first and later unnest/explode those lists..  but your approach sounds better and looks promising. I'm performing some tests now with your code but I think this is the exact answer I was looking for. Thank you! will update soon..